# rich:extendedDataTable rendered in readonly mode

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I am using JSF2.0, rich faces 4.2.2, tomcat 6.0.35 for my application.
On one of the pages, there are two rich:extendedDataTable components for 'tablelist' and 'tablecontent'.
On click of row of tablelist datatable, an ajax call is made and tablecontent datatable is rendered.
The issue is that the rendered datatable is non editable, i.e., I cannot select the row or perform other operation like click, etc.

Below is the code:

```
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellspacing="0"  >  

       <rich:extendedDataTable value="#{tableBean.tableList}"  var="o" id="table1" iterationStatusVar="it" style="width:200px;height:400px;" onrowclick="select('#{o.name}');"
        <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Table List" style="align:left;"></h:outputText>
        </f:facet>  
        <rich:column width="199px" id="tablist" >  
                <h:outputText value="#{o.name}"/>  
        </rich:column>              
       </rich:extendedDataTable> 

      <rich:extendedDataTable value="#{tableBean.rows}"  var="r" id="tableHum" iterationStatusVar="it" style="width:400px;height:400px;" >
        <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Table content" style="align:left;"></h:outputText>
        </f:facet>  
        <c:forEach items="#{tableBean.columns}" var="c" varStatus="i">
            <rich:column  >
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="#{c}" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{r[i.index]}" style="align:center;"/> 
            </rich:column>
        </c:forEach>

    </rich:extendedDataTable>

      </h:panelGrid>
      <a4j:jsFunction name="select" action="#{tableBean.getTableData}" render="tableHum" execute="@this" status="tableDataStatus" >
    <a4j:param name="param1" assignTo="#{tableBean.tableName}" />
            </a4j:jsFunction>
      </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Anyone has idea?

Answer (score 0):

Hi there I think I had a similar problem
I would recommend you to try `a4j:repeat` and `a4j:outputPanel`